# turning files into .tar in vagrant

Tags: windows, vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox

i've tried fixing the problem ***`"bsdtar: Error opening archive: Unrecognized archive format"`*** #161 but i didnt find an anwser ,
(im using 1.7.4 vagrant which is the latest version.

i tried this approach first :

```
C:\Users\1>vagrant box add pip C:\Users\1\Desktop
==> box: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...
==> box: Adding box 'pip' (v0) for provider:
    box: Unpacking necessary files from: file://C:/Users/1/Desktop
    box:
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.

Couldn't open file /Users/1/Desktop
```

after failing i tried importing the file through a url,making me get the error on top.:

```
C:\Users\1>vagrant box add pip https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
==> box: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...
==> box: Adding box 'pip' (v0) for provider:
    box: Downloading: https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
    box: Progress: 100% (Rate: 826k/s, Estimated time remaining: --:--:--
The box failed to unpackage properly. Please verify that the box
file you're trying to add is not corrupted and try again. The
output from attempting to unpackage (if any):

bsdtar.EXE: Error opening archive: Unrecognized archive format
```

Comment: which version of vagrant you're using ? try getting latest version, it should fix

Comment: my version of vagrant is 1.7.4 and its the latest one yet.

Comment: What's your actual problem?

Answer (score 0):

Vagrant expects either a box path/url or a name of the box that is available on [Vagrant Atlas](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/boxes/search). You give it just arbitrary things that do not contain a box.

To e.g. download the [Ubuntu Trusty x64](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64) box, use

```
vagrant box add ubuntu/trusty64
```